# Gremlin: How to get duplicates in a graph?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Assume I have a graph with vertices that have property `name`, what is a good way to get Ids of all vertices that have the same name.

Extending this, if I have a graph with `day` and `month` properties, how to return IDs of these vertices that share the same values.

Comment: Did any of the solutions below work out for you? ps: would be useful if you mark them as a solution, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't know the value of the duplicates and you just want to find all duplicates possible:

Here is a quick and dirty solution for you. Use [Group By](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/reference/#group-step), for example:

```
g.V().has("name").limit(50).group().by("name");
```

I only use `limit` because doing this operation on the whole graph will be very time consuming. For the `day` and `month` properties you can do the same thing.

Comment: It's not really "the same thing" for multiple properties. For `day` and `month` it would be `.group().by(valueMap("day","month"))`.

Comment: How would you eliminate any group that has only one vertex in it?

Comment: Not sure how to do that within the traversal itself. There is a `groupCount` predicate that may be of use but not sure how. `g.V().has("DEGREE").limit(50).groupCount().by("name")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created indices for these indexed properties before you created the vertices, then you can create a gremlin query like:

`def g = graph.traversal(); def vertices = g.V().has("name", "David").id();`

This assumes you know the value you are searching for.